# Returning Qt RemoteObjects from RemoteObject method calls

Tags: qt, qt5, remoteobject

I'm trying to setup a remote object for a given class.
The class return pointer to internal objects.

```
class A
{
...
    func(){ };
}
class B
{
std::vector<A> AObjects;
...
    A *addObject(){}
}
```

I created the rep file like this

```
class A
{
    SLOT(func())
}
class B
{
    SLOT(A* addObject())
}
```

This causes errors because the generated code tries to serialize A to transfer it to the cient/replica side.
What I want is a RemoteObject of A to get transferred to call func remotely from the client side.
The number of A Object depends on the remote calls of addObject.

Is there a way to get the such a system with qt remote objects?

One way I could imagine is to set the returntype in B to the generated Replica class.

```
class A
{
    SLOT(func())
}
class B
{
    SLOT(AReplica addObject())
}
```

But then the generated code must be available also at server side and the headers need to be in the right inclusion order.

Addition: Replica objects are not serializable either.

**Edit:**

To get the desired behavior I changed the rep-file

```
class Object
{
    SLOT(print(QString& i_oString));
};

class ObjectGenerator
{
    SLOT(QString genObj())
};
```

The implementation of the server looks like this:

```
QString Server::genObj()
{
    auto obj = new Obj();
    auto objRep = QString::number(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(obj)); //pinter as unique string reference
    m_oHost.enableRemoting(obj, objRep);
    qDebug() << "generated object: " << objRep << endl;
    return objRep;
}
```

The client can now trigger object generations and retrieve the replica

```
auto obj = reptr->genObj();
obj.waitForFinished();
auto rep = m_node.acquire<ObjectReplica>(obj.returnValue());
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(printSignal(QString&)), rep, SLOT(print(QString &)));
```

In this implementation I need to wrap the client side to get a usable interface.

**Is there a more qt-like way of doing this?**

Comment: Strange task... Why don't use [Dynamic Replica](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/remoteobjects-example-dynamic-replica.html) ? Seems it is designed specifically for this.

Comment: I saw the example on the qt website, but it looked like the same behavior, as the server side is not changed to use dynamic replica

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain the conditions of the problem. What domain functionality do you want to implement?